# CodeIgniter Self-Join doesn't match SQL

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Alright, have to be missing something here.

My SQL works fine:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.material, t2.id, t2.material, t3.id, t3.material, t4.id, t4.material
FROM ml_levels t1 

LEFT JOIN ml_levels t2 
ON t1.parentID = t2.id

LEFT JOIN ml_levels t3
ON t2.parentID = t3.id

LEFT JOIN ml_levels t4
ON t3.parentID = t4.id

WHERE t1.id = 286
```

This returns

```
id   |  material  | id  |  material         |  id  |  material            | id |  material
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
286  |  4Layer    | 209 |  Protective Film  |  60  |  Specialty Products  | 1  |  Protect
```

However, my ActiveRecord is only returning t4.id and t4.material:

```
    $this->db->select('t1.id, t1.material, t2.id, t2.material, t3.id, t3.material, t4.id, t4.material');
    $this->db->from('ml_levels AS t1')->where('t1.id',286);
    $this->db->join('ml_levels AS t2','t1.parentID = t2.id','left');
    $this->db->join('ml_levels AS t3','t2.parentID = t3.id','left');
    $this->db->join('ml_levels AS t4','t3.parentID = t4.id','left');

    return $this->db->get()->row();
```

this returns:

```
id   |  material  |
-------------------
1    |  Protect   |
```

$this->db->last_query() returns:

```
SELECT `t1`.`id`, `t1`.`material`, `t2`.`id`, `t2`.`material`, `t3`.`id`, `t3`.`material`, `t4`.`id`, `t4`.`material` 
FROM (`ml_levels` AS t1) 
LEFT JOIN `ml_levels` AS t2 ON `t1`.`parentID` = `t2`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `ml_levels` AS t3 ON `t2`.`parentID` = `t3`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `ml_levels` AS t4 ON `t3`.`parentID` = `t4`.`id` 
WHERE `t1`.`id` = 286
```

And if I run this SQL on the database, it returns exactly what the original query returned.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Please run `echo $this->db->last_query();` after the query and post the output here.

Comment: @NickBrown Please edit your answer with this output. Its not readable in the comments section.

Comment: @orourkek

I've tried running the statement on several different records to make sure that it isn't that particular record, and I've also pored over the CI ActiveRecord self and left join documentation to make sure my syntax is correct.

Comment: Please post an example of the output expected vs the output received.

Comment: @NickBrown Also, have you tried running the output of `$this->db->last_query()` directly? The only noticeable difference between the queries you posted is the `AS` keyword and escaping the column names.  **edit: just saw your edit, never mind** :]

Comment: Added the expected output vs received output.

Comment: Put an alias in your columns to make them unique and see if it works.

Comment: @Sérgio Michels - Sorry, I don't follow.  All of my statements have `AS t*` and the column names in the select statement are named accordingly.

Comment: @NickBrown you have t1.material and t2.material, just put an alias in t2.material with some other name, maybe this is messing up your result.

Comment: The real question is why do you keep joining the same table on itself? If this is necessary to achieve the result you've posted, I think you need to redesign your database.

Comment: @Catfish Actually, this IS the re-design.  It was originally a series of 6 tables that all had very similar information that could be condensed into one table.

It's for a breadcrumb-like hierarchy.  So each material has a parent, but that parent exists in the same table -- 4 levels of hierarchy = original query + 3 joins to get the entire series of levels.

Comment: Well this is still not a good redesign. I don't know your datamodel or i'd help you out, but you should never need to write queries like this if your data model is more normolized.

Comment: @Catfish  It's not complex, just  id,material,level,parentID.  I didn't see a reason to break each level of product into a different table when they could all reside in one.

Comment: It could definitely be a scale issue if you ever had large amounts of data. What does it hurt having a few extra tables? It makes your queries much easier to write. It may work in this case, but i'd suggest reading up on database normalization.

Comment: @Catfish Well, the issue was the original 6 tables required 5 different joins to actually assemble the needed information.  I felt like it was an improvement to cut it to 1 table and 3 self-joins, granted that may be incorrect.  I'll poke around the internet for some info on normalization, though.

Comment: 6 tables may have not been a good solution either. Again i can't see your data so it's hard to say exactly. Maybe this is a very edge case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeigniter return only field name without table label so that you found only two fields because there are only `id` and `material`. Change line:

```
 $this->db->select('t1.id, t1.material, t2.id, t2.material, t3.id, t3.material, t4.id, t4.material');
```

with:

```
 $this->db->select('t1.id AS t1id, t1.material AS t1material, t2.id AS t2id, t2.material AS t2material, t3.id AS t3id, t3.material AS t3material, t4.id AS t4id, t4.material AS t4material');
```